# cakephp 3 matching not working

Tags: cakephp, matching, model-associations, cakephp-3.2

I have `categories`, `products` and `seller_products` table and want to select all from three tables group by categories where `seller_products.stock > 0` and `seller_products.status = 1`

This is my code

```
$pros1 = $this->Products->Categories->find()
      ->where([
    ])
->select(['Categories.id', 'Categories.title'])
->distinct(['Categories.id'])
->contain(['Products'])
->matching('Products.SellerProducts', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
   return $q->where(['SellerProducts.stock >' => 0, 'SellerProducts.status' => 1]);
});
```

**But this is not working. I'm getting all products group by categories by matching is not working and still getting products whose stock is 0 or status is not 1**

Their associations are

```
$categories->hasMany('Products');
$products->hasMany('SellerProducts');
```

Comment: What was the generated query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that `contain()` and `matching()` are different. You are asking for categories having products where there is stock. But if you want what products are those that matched, you need to filter them in `contain()` as well:

```
$matcher = function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
   return $q->where(['SellerProducts.stock >' => 0, 'SellerProducts.status' => 1]);
};


$pros1 = $this->Products->Categories->find()
    ->select(['Categories.id', 'Categories.title'])
    ->distinct(['Categories.id'])
    ->contain(['Products' => function ($q) use ($matcher) {
         return $q->matching('SellerProducts', $matcher);
    }])
    ->matching('Products.SellerProducts', $matcher);
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `matching`? You would get exactly the same result?